# Opentok-reactjs styling not applying for publisher & subscriber

Tags: reactjs, opentok, tokbox

I am trying to apply width & height to publisher & subscriber, but unable to solve it. Do anyone can help me with this issue?
even tried with `OTPublisherContainer` & `OTSubscriberContainer` also...

Here is the sample code:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYD2x.png]

Answer (score 0):

After checking the source code, it doesn't look like the `styles` prop is supported: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react/blob/master/src/OTPublisher.js#L177

Answer (score 0):

OTPublisher has a `properties` prop.

You can set it as follows

`<OTPublisher properties={{width:400, height:400}} />`

Reference:
https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/OT.html#initSession